# How to apply different classes on different elements based on the text inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**HTML**

```
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-401 dt-mega-menu mega-auto-width mega-column-3">
    <a href='#' data-level='1'>
        <i class="logo-png dnld-logo"></i>
        <span class="menu-item-text">
                <span class="menu-text">Download App</span>
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-71">
    <a href='#' data-level='1'>
        <i class="logo-png subs-logo"></i>
        <span class="menu-item-text">
                <span class="menu-text">Purchase Subscription</span>
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-74 has-children">
    <a href='#' class='not-clickable-item' data-level='1'>
        <i class="logo-png help-logo"></i>
        <span class="menu-item-text">
                <span class="menu-text">Help</span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-nav gradient-hover hover-style-click-bg level-arrows-on">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-66 first">
            <a href='#' data-level='2'>
                <i class="logo-png faqs-logo"></i>
                <span class="menu-item-text">
                        <span class="menu-text">FAQS</span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-68">
            <a href='#' data-level='2'>
                <i class="logo-png vid-logo"></i>
                <span class="menu-item-text">
                        <span class="menu-text">Instructional Videos</span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

There are more than 20 elements like that. And there is a different class for the inner most span which should only be applied if it is clicked. The classes only contain the color of text.

**JQuery**

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('li.act > a > i').removeClass('logo-png').addClass('activatedd');

        function addEventListenerByClass(className, event, fn) {
            var list = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
            for (var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
                list[i].addEventListener(event, fn, true);
            }
        }

        addEventListenerByClass('menu-item', 'click', showIcon);

        var cssClasses = ['home-text', 'about-text', 'print-text', 'dnld-text', 'subs-text', 'help-text', 'sorks-text', 'cont-text', 'work-text', 'col-text', 'body-text', 'hst-text', 'space-text', 'cell-text', 'organ-text', 'system-text', 'cs-text', 'ae-text', 'ag-text', 'bsi-text', 'med-text', 'tudors-text', 'roma-text', 'vict-text', 'vik-text', 'ww-text', 'ss-text', 'pe-text', 'sc-text', 'faqs-text', 'vid-text', 'email-text', 'trial-text', 'next-text'];


        function showIcon() {
            $("#primary-menu .act").removeClass("act");
            $("#primary-menu .activatedd").removeClass("activatedd").addClass("logo-png");
            //Add active class for is parent if it is level 1
            $(this).addClass("act").parents("li").addClass("act");
            $('> a > i', $(this)).removeClass("logo-png").addClass("activatedd").parents().find("li.act>a>i.logo-png").removeClass("logo-png").addClass("activatedd");
        }
    })
})(jQuery);
```

`var cssClasses` contains all the classes that we have to apply. Now for the given HTML, `<span class="menu-text">Download App</span>` will be applied `dnld-text` class. But when some other element is clicked, say **FAQs**, this class needs to be removed and **FAQs**'s class and its parent's class needs to be applied. 
The javascript function  wrote does about the same thing for icons but it is applying same class and removing same class from all elements. We can also single out the elements based on the class of  i.e. `$('i + span > span')`. How am i supposed to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I understand your issue you don't need to add those classes at all just use CSS with an structure targeting when the `i` element has the class `.activatedd` like this for example for the *Download Text*:

So the same you already have on CSS for `.dnld-text` must be

```
i.dnld-logo.activatedd + .menu-item-text .menu-text {
  color:red;
}
```

Step by step:

- Target the element `menu-text`
- Child of `menu-item-text` who is
- Sibling of the `i` element with class `dnld-logo` and when is `activatedd`

Comment: I'm very sure this'll work just fine. Let me try. Thanks!

Comment: @UmerFarooq yeah mate give it a try that way you can't avoid after the removing of all specific classnames

Comment: I love you man! This thing has been driving me crazy for 3 days now. Works perfectly! :)

Comment: @UmerFarooq really glad to help U mate